# I am getting this error. Page not found (404) Request Method: GET Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/

Tags: python

my polls app/views.py

```
from django.http import Http404   
from django.shortcuts import render    
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):   
    return HttpResponse("hello this is venkat from lakshmipuram.")

def detail(request, question_id):
    return HttpResponse("You're looking at question %s." % question_id)

def results(request, question_id):    
    response = "You're looking at the results of question %s."
    return HttpResponse(response % question_id)

def vote(request, question_id):    
    return HttpResponse("You're voting on question %s." % question_id)
```

my polls app/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path    
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    # ex: /polls/    
    path('', views.index, name='index'),

    # ex: /polls/5/    
    path('<int:question_id>/', views.detail, name='detail'),

    # ex: /polls/5/results/    
    path('<int:question_id>/results/', views.results, name='results'),

    # ex: /polls/5/vote/    
    path('<int:question_id>/vote/', views.vote, name='vote'),
]
```

my project/urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin    
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [    
    path('', include('polls.urls')),    
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Comment: Please state the question in the content and any extra detail which could help solve it https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

change your project/urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin    
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [    
    path('polls/', include('polls.urls')),    
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```